# CSS Transform Animation for a Virtualized Carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel

I have a carousel component with a virtualized list of images. In other words, the component accepts an `images` prop which can contain many images to display, but it keeps track of a `currIndex` and only holds the images `currIndex-1`, `currIndex`, and `currIndex+1` in DOM.

```
interface CarouselProps {
  images: Array<Image>;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  ...
}

export const Carousel = (props: CarouselProps) => {
  const [indices, setIndices] = React.useState([images.length - 1, 0, 1]);

  function handlePrevClick() {
    // if `indices` is [2, 3, 4], set it to [1, 2, 3]
    // also handles wrapping around
  }

  function handleNextClick() {
    // if `indices` is [2, 3, 4], set it to [3, 4, 5]
    // also handles wrapping around
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper width={width} height={height}>
      <Scroller size={width}>
        {indices.map((index) => {
          const { src, alt } = images[index];
          return (
            <ImageContainer key={src} width={width} height={height}>
              <img src={src} alt={alt} />
            </ImageContainer>
          );
        })}
      </Scroller>
      
      // JSX for navigation buttons...
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

How can I add a sliding animation to the carousel when I click the Next or Prev button? **The part I'm not clear on is that**, if without virtualization, I could move `<Scroller />` by `currIndex * image_width` using CSS transform.

```
display: flex;
transform: translate(${currIndex * image_width}px);
transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
```

But if I wanna keep virtualization, I would always be transforming `<Scroller />` by `image_width` amount.

How should I change my CSS so that it finds the right image to slide to, while keeping the virtualization?